# Using service.rb in rails - getting No Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use services in rails to reduce the size of the controller. 
I have an Event model with fields user_id among others. I would like to select the top 3 users who have organised the most events. This is the first time using Services, and i was told it is highly recommended to keep the model skinny as well as the controller.

My billboard_service.rb:

```
class BillboardService


  attr_reader :user, :params, :event



  def most_event_organized
    Event.group(:user_id).order('count_all desc').count.first(3)
  end


  def event_find(user_id)
    Event.where(user_id: user_id).includes(:user_id)
  end

end
```

My view (very early stage):

```
<%= @bill_board.most_event_organized %>
```

And my controller is as built by scaffold. 
I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `most_event_organized' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div class="line_separation_equilibree"></div>
    2: <h3> league </h3>
    3: <%= @bill_board.most_event_organized %>
    4: <div class="col-lg-4">
    5: 
    6: <br>
```

Does someone knows how this should work please? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you try `<%= BillboardService.new.most_event_organized %>` in your view or in your controller, you will have to get the instance of `@bill_board` and then in your view, you can have it accessible.

Comment: Ok, after modifying my Service.rb and using your code, it works. I get `[[1, 6], [12, 5], [9, 2]]` as a result, so user_id(1) have 6 events. Now need to figure out how to make it in a nice table.

What is the logic behind the "new" in your code please ? trying to understand how this works.

Comment: The method you're calling `most_event_organized` is an instance method, meaning, it can be accessed by an `object` which is an instance of class `BillboardService`. So, when you're calling the method in your `views`, like say `@billboard.most_event_organized`, the error you got was `nil`, meaning the object(@billboard) was `nil`, hence `BillboardService.new` will initialize an object and using that you were able to call the method.

Comment: Undersood, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new BillboardService object before calling the method

```
@bill_board = BillboardService.new()
@bill_board.most_event_organized
```